# Contractible Banach algebras

Tags: ra.rings-and-algebras, oa.operator-algebras, banach-algebras, amenability

A Banach algebra $A$ is contractible if $H^1(A, X)=0$ for all Banach $A$-bimodules $X$. Now to my question

> Let $A$ be Banach algebra and $I$ be closed ideal of $A$. If $I$ and $A/I$  are both contractible, then is $A$ contractible?

**My attempt:**
Let $X$ be a Banach $A$-bimodules, and let $D\in \mathcal{Z^{1}}(A, X)$, then $D_{|_I}\in \mathcal{Z^{1}}(I, X)$ since $I$ contractible, there is $x\in X$ such that $$Da= a.x-x.a=ad_x(a) $$ for all $a\in I$. Let $\bar{D}=D-ad_x$, then $\bar{D}_{|_I}=0$.

I'm stuck here, Does anyone have a recommendation of how to continue?

I am grateful for anyone to have a good recommendation of books//lectures/resources/etc.? for contractible Banach algebra  Thanks.

Comment: If you have access to Johnson's 1972 memoir, or Runde's book, then they should have complete proofs of the corresponding result for amenability. You should then be able (this is my intuition and not a certain prediction) to adapt those proofs

Comment: That said, note that $\overline{D}$ is a derivation on $A$ which vanishes on $I$. So it factors through the quotient map $q:A\to A/I$ as $\overline{D}= D_2 \circ q$ where $D_2: A/I \to X$. Can you show that $D_2$ is a derivation?

Comment: @Yemon Choi, If I show $D_2$ is a derivation, then there is an $x_2 \in X$ such that $D_2=ad_{x_2}$ but I'm stuck here again

Comment: Since any contractible Banach algebra has a unit (as any amenable Banach algebra has b.a.i.), an ideal of it is nothing but a direct summand.

Comment: @NarutakaOZAWA did you have a short argument in mind for this? I agree that any ideal which is complemented as a Banach space in $A$ is a direct summand in the algebraic sense, i.e. a summand as a Banach $A$-bimodule. But I don't recall being able to strengthen this to drop the complementation hypothesis, unless one adds some approximation property assumptions

Comment: @NarutakaOZAWA In fact, K(E) is always an ideal in B(E) for any Banach space E, and K(E) being a summand of B(E) would imply K(E) is unital, which would imply E is finite-dimensional. But as you know, contractibility of B(E) remains an open problem at this level of generality... so have I misunderstood your comment?

Comment: @Yemon Choi: (0) The way I wrote was confusing. I meant $I$ is unital because it is contractible. (1) If $B$ is contractible and non-unital, then $B$ is a $B$-bimodule w.r.t. the usual left multiplication and zero right multiplication. Then the formal identity map on $B$ is a derivation, which must be inner by contractibility. This means $B$ has a right unit. Likewise for the left. (2) Contractibility of $B(E)$ doesn't imply that of $K(E)$.